# Modelling Two Way Relationship in Unity for Scriptable Objects

Tags: unity, architecture, software-engineering, databases, scriptable-object

How does one model two-way relationships for scriptable objects?

Let's say we have a number of items in-game, and each item can be obtained by different conditions. Some may require you to complete a certain mission, some may be purchasable from an NPC, some may be dropped from an enemy, and some may require you to purchase a DLC...

Given an item, we would like to know what are the ways that it could be obtained; and given a mission/npc/enemy/dlc, we would like to know what items it grants.

How can I model two way relationships like this?

For items alone, it may be easy to handle... but as you can imagine, there are a lot more two-way relationships in games, between missions and NPC, missions and missions, DLC and NPC... and so on.

Comment: What's the point of this? Are we now doing opinion polls to decide software architectures for people?

Comment: @Philipp Ideally not! That's why I recommended moving the proposed solutions outside of the question, so it's not read as "which of these options do you think I should pick?" and instead asks "what is a way to solve this problem". Each of the answers proposes a way to solve the problem. Maybe through other users' input — adding new answers, comments, votes — one answer will stand out as clearly superior, but even if not, the question is answered. That's my thinking on it at the moment at least — absolutely open to edits or alternative proposals to make this question as constructive as possible

Comment: @DMGregory First thoughts when viewing this (before seeing the comments): "Why did the asker post three different answers on _his own_ question? Oh, that way we can vote on which solution we think is best. That's actually pretty clever!"

Comment: "we would like to know what are the ways that it could be obtained" Are you talking about within the game, or would this only be for developer reference in the Unity Editor? This is an important question because performance is less important for developer tools in the Editor.

Answer (score 1):

I think this problem calls for another layer of abstraction. So i think it’s not a two-way relationship, but rather two one-way relationships.

Let’s take the example of a sword. This could be Dropped from monsters, Sold in a shop, etc etc.

So a sword could implement IDroppable, ISellable interfaces.

A store would have a list of ISellables and a monster would have a list of IDroppables.

This concept is called composition. You compose an object with properties that give it some functionality.

My example above uses interfaces. Another common way, is instead of the class Sword implementing the interface, the sword would have a set  of components. Like Sellable Droppable etc. Whichever way you choose has pros and cons but the idea is similar. For scriptable objects, I suspect the component approach is better since Unity doesn’t play too nice with interfaces. So In my projects I would have something like

`List<CollectionSource>` where IDroppable and ISellable are both Collectionsources. And then do (pseudo code) `if list.contains(any IDroppable )` then we know it’s droppable.

To find out which monsters drop your sword, you could now write an editor  window that scans your project for any store scriptable objects. And then scan each of their inventories to see if they contain the sword. If so, add them to the list in the window.

To find out how the sword can be obtained you need only look at which components/interfaces it has. A legendary weapon might only have a IUnlockable component and no ISellable, meaning stores can’t possibly have it. It can only be provided by situations that can provide Unlockables.

So we’ve changed the 2 way relationship into:

- **How is it collected?** Does it have IDroppable?
- **What monsters drop it?** Does sword have IDroppable? Search all monsters for having sword (as an IDroppable) in their drop list

Aside: Creating a list of IDroppables that is unity-inspector-friendly is not easy. For example a monster’s drop list. The easiest way I’ve found is to use abstract classes as a base for your component. But then you lose the full power and polymorphism of interfaces or full components. Other ways might be to have the list be of type Item, but then use the OnValidate function to weed out anything that isn’t an IDroppable. I tend to use both depending on the situation and the exact way I want to scale things up.

Answer (score 0):

Have two scriptable objects references each other, but it's error prone. So we will need to have some validation logic, or an editor script that updates relationship automatically when one was changed. Also it would be time-consuming to write scripts for all the different relationships that needs to be accessed two ways.

Perhaps a third scriptable object can be used to store the relationship, and custom tooling can be made to automatically update the value on the two scriptable objects.

Answer (score 0):

Make one-way reference only, and have the two-way relationships initialized at runtime.

But what if we want to have the relationship displayed in the Unity Editor two-way? A possible solution is to write a script that iterates through all scriptable objects and build a relationship graph between scriptable objects, but it would also be very time-consuming.

So a solution could be to abstract the scriptable objects and create a base class/interface for all relational scriptable objects. Then, let each class reports their relationship (and sub-relationship) through an abstract property, and iterate from the root object to build the relationship graph for both edit and play mode.

Answer (score 0):

Use an actual relational database like SQLlite to store the relationship, and perhaps an id/guid reference to the actual scriptable object for easy editing within the Unity Editor. Or maybe, just ditch scriptable object completely.

There also seem to be [some relational databases specifically made for Unity](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/bg-database-112262), with Unity data types support, and it may work for your case.

Answer (score 0):

If this is only used for developer reference in the Unity Editor, and you only need to check one item at a time, you can do something like this (searching through each relevant asset in the game to find references):

```
public class NPC : ScriptableObject {
    [SerializeField] private List<Item> dropOnDeath;
    public IReadOnlyList<Item> DropOnDeath => dropOnDeath;
}

public struct ItemQuantity {
    public Item item;
    public int quantity;
}

public class Shop : ScriptableObject {
    [SerializeField] private List<ItemQuantity> inventory;
    public IReadOnlyList<ItemQuantity> Inventory => inventory;
}

public class Quest : ScriptableObject {
    [SerializeField] private List<Item> itemRewards;
    public IReadOnlyList<Item> ItemRewards => itemRewards;
}

[CustomEditor(typeof(Item))]
public class ItemEditor : Editor<Item> {
    private List<UnityEngine.Object> sources = new List<UnityEngine.Object>();

    override void OnInspectorGUI() {
        var item = (Item)target;

        if (GUILayout.Button("Find references")) {
            sources.Clear();
            //search each asset that can contain a reference to an item
            List<NPC> npcs = GetAssetsOfType<NPC>();
            foreach (var npc in npcs) {
                if (npc.DropOnDeath.Contains(item)) sources.Add(npc);
            }
            List<Shop> shops = GetAssetsOfType<Shop>();
            foreach (var shop in shops) {
                foreach (var itemQuantity in shop.Inventory) {
                    if (itemQuantity.item == item) {
                        sources.Add(shop);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            List<Quest> quests = GetAssetsOfType<Quest>();
            foreach (var quest in quests) {
                if (quest.ItemRewards.Contains(item)) sources.Add(quest);
            }
        }

        EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Item Sources:");
        foreach (var source in sources) {
            EditorGUILayout.LabelField($"\t{source.Name}");
        }
    }

    List<T> GetAssetsOfType<T>() where T : UnityEngine.Object {
        string filter = $"t:{typeof(T).Name}";
        var guids = AssetDatabase.FindAssets(filter);
        List<T> assets = new List<T>(guids.Length);
        foreach (var guid in guids) {
            string path = AssetDatabase.GUIDToAssetPath(guid);
            T asset = AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath<T>(path);
            assets.Add(asset);
        }
        return assets;
    }
}
```

(Note that I have not tested this and it may contain typos).

How well this scales depends on the scope of your game.

Answer (score 0):

If this is only for developer reference in the Editor, and you only need to check one item at a time, another tool you can use is the free package [Asset Usage Detector](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/utilities/asset-usage-detector-112837) from the Unity Asset Store.

It can find references to an asset in scenes, prefabs, and Scriptable Objects. I'm guessing that it works by scanning the files for the asset's GUID, though I've never dug through the code to find out. It's a little awkward to use sometimes, but may be easier than creating your own process for mapping the relationships between assets.